# Dismissing the Current View from SwiftUI Toolbar takes me to root view

Tags: swiftui

I have Three Views: Test1, Test2, Test3. I have a NavigationView on Test1, and a navigation link that takes me to Test2. In Test2, I have a NavigationLink that takes me to Test3, as well as a button that dismisses the current view, and takes me to Test1. In Test3, I just have a button that dismisses the current view, and takes me to Test2. All is well in this scenario.

Here is the complete code:

```
struct Test1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Test2()) {
                Text("Click Me")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Test 1")
        }
    }
}

struct Test2: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: Test3()) {
                Text("Click Me")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Test 2")
                         
            Button("Return") {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct Test3: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Button("Return") {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Test 3")
    }
}
```

Now, in Test2, if I move the NavigationLink into a toolbar, so that this is clickable from the Navigation Bar, that is where I am encountering strange behavior. When I click the link in the toolbar to go to Test3, and when I click the Return button in Test3, I am now taken back to Test1, and not Test2 as I would have expected. Here is the revised Test2 code:

```
struct Test2: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Return") {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Test 2")
        .toolbar {
             NavigationLink(destination: Test3()) {
                 Text("Test 3")
             }
         }

    }
}
```

How can I have a NavigationLink in Test2, and not be taken back to the root view when dismissed from Test3?

Comment: Seems like the problem is from `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` now deprecated in iOS15, tried it on iOS14 i had the same bug as you. on iOS15 beta with the new `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss` you don't have this bug.

Comment: Building for iOS 15 means that I don't support iOS 14, right? I wonder if there is a solution that lets me get around this for iOS 14 (and earlier) devices?

Comment: Yeah i don't know any valuable solution for iOS14 sorry. One thing could "Maybe" work is to not use the toolbar modifier and make custom navigation buttons with `.navigationBarHidden(true)` but it will take you more work to make sure everything is set up properly